# pmd rule not included but executed by gradle

Tags: gradle, pmd

gradle-5.1
pmd-plugin

gradle pmdMain produces lots of errors of type DataflowAnomalyAnalysis although that rule is excluded explicitely.

from build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id: 'pmd'
}

pmd {
    ignoreFailures = true
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/pmd")
    ruleSetFiles = files("config/pmd/ruleset.xml")
}
```

from ruleset.xml (only rule):

```
< rule ref="category/java/errorprone.xml">
    < exclude name="DataflowAnomalyAnalysis"/>
< /rule>
```

How can i REALLY exclude that rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Gradle PMD Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html) has two properties to configure rules:

- ruleSetFiles
- ruleSets

The property [ruleSets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension:ruleSets) has enabled by default a couple of rulesets (errorprone and bestpractices).

In order to execute only the rules specified in `ruleSetFiles`, you'll need to set `ruleSets` explicitly to a empty list, e.g.

```
pmd {
    ignoreFailures = true
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/pmd")
    ruleSetFiles = files("config/pmd/ruleset.xml")
    ruleSets = []
}
```